# Javascript array assignment issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-assignment

I'm trying to assign a series of 81 boxes an automatic i.d number through use of a three-level nested four loop. Here's my code.

```
function printBoxes()
    {
        alert("Function Entered");
        var box = new Array();
        alert("Array Created");


        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for(var k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    box[i, j ,k] = [i, j, k];
                }
            }
        }

        alert(box[3,5,1]);

        alert("Arrays Created");

        for(var a = 0; a < 9; a++)
        {
            document.writeln("<br>");

            for(var b = 0; b < 3; b++)
            {
                for(var c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                {   document.writeln("<FORM inputs>")
                    document.write("<INPUT type = 'text' id = ' " + box[a,b,c] + " ' value = ' " + box[a,b,c] + "' size = '1' maxlength = '1'/>");
                    document.writeln("<//FORM>")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is this: though I can use an alert box to see that each box is being assigned a proper id, after it leaves the main for loop, I end up with 1/3 820s, 821, and 822 respectively. How do I fix this?

Comment: @minitech it most certainly does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Example.3A_Creating_a_two-dimensional_array

Comment: @ExplosionPills: That’s an array of arrays. Whether this is a multidimensional array is debatable, but you’ll notice that it doesn’t use the comma syntax anyways.

Comment: @minitech the documentation says "two-dimensional."  I don't think there's any debate about the definitions of "dimension" and "multi."

Comment: @ExplosionPills: MDN is a wiki. Given that we’re debating about it, it’s debatable ;)

Answer (score 7):

There are no special-case multidimensional arrays in JavaScript — only arrays, which can contain arrays. So create a new array for each dimension each time:

```
var box = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    box[i] = [];

    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        box[i][j] = [];

        for(var k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            box[i][j][k] = [i, j, k];
        }
    }
}
```

… for example. The reason this pretends to work is that JavaScript has a comma operator that will evaluate its operands and return the right one, so `box[i, j, k]` really just means `box[k]`.

Comment: All this does is make the ids absurd numbers like " 1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,2,1,1,0,1,1,1" (Which is three ids in one) and make some of them undefined.

Comment: @Existential_Realist: First off: did you change all the `box[*, *, *]` to `box[*][*][*]`? Second off, `box[3][5][1]` is not a valid index. The second “level” only has indices 0, 1, and 2 each.